# Excel IRR: Can I use range reference inside IRR with math inside {}?

Tags: arrays, excel, irr

Good morning. In post "Excel IRR: can I use it referencing a combination of cells and fixed numbers? IRR({-10,11+A2})" is said we can math inside {} using CHOOSE function. But if I have first payment (investment) in B1, 100, and rest of income in a range, B2:B6, (10,10,10,10,70), then, when I try

=IRR(CHOOSE({1,2};-B1,E2:E6))

I receive a #¡VALUE! result with ENTER or CSE. I use an spanish version of Excel 2013, where separator is ";" instead ",". I have try

=IRR(CHOOSE({1,2};(-B1,E2:E6)))

without success. Ideally I would like make some additional calculations in first cell, for example -B1+cell1+cell2 ...

Thank in advance

Comment: Troubleshoot by examining the array returned by `=CHOOSE({1,2};-B1,E2:E6)` to ensure it returns the array of values you are expecting.